# mysql innodb altering two tables that have foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Below is my current database structure

```
CREATE TABLE one (
  id           MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE two (
  id           MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  one_id       MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`one_Id`) REFERENCES `one` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

How can I run the following alter command on both tables

```
ALTER TABLE one MODIFY COLUMN `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment;
ALTER TABLE two MODIFY COLUMN `one_id` int(10) NOT NULL;
```

Right now I'm getting this error

```
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename (errno: 150)
```

I've also tried to disable these but it doesn't help

```
 SET autocommit=0; 
 SET unique_checks=0; 
 SET foreign_key_checks=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your constraint name in table `two` is `two_ibfk_1` , you can see the name of the constraint with this command :
    SHOW CREATE TABLE `two`;

so the command would be to delete the constraint first, and then recreate it after it was modified

```
ALTER TABLE two DROP FOREIGN KEY two_ibfk_1;
ALTER TABLE one MODIFY COLUMN `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment;
ALTER TABLE two MODIFY COLUMN `one_id` int(10) NOT NULL ;
ALTER TABLE two ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`one_Id`) REFERENCES `one` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

FYI, the second command to modify table `two` can not be set as auto_increment, because the primary is is column `id`

Comment: is there any way to not have to drop the foreign key? I simplified the example there are many

Answer (score 0):

This is straight from the [a ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html) documentation for MySQL:

> Before MySQL 5.6.7, using ALTER TABLE to change the definition of a
>   foreign key column could cause a loss of referential integrity. For
>   example, changing a foreign key column that contained NULL values to
>   be NOT NULL caused the NULL values to be the empty string. Similarly,
>   an ALTER TABLE IGNORE that removed rows in a parent table could break
>   referential integrity.
>
> As of 5.6.7, the server prohibits changes to foreign key columns with
>   the potential to cause loss of referential integrity. A workaround is
>   to use ALTER TABLE ... DROP FOREIGN KEY before changing the column
>   definition and ALTER TABLE ... ADD FOREIGN KEY afterward.

This makes the other answer correct. The `SET foreign_key_checks=0;` statement and its brethren will disable constraints, but will not let you modify a table such that an existing constraint can no longer even exist.